# Main Window is not resizable when Child Windows is opened in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, scroll, childwindow

I am wondering is someone has a solution for it. Main Window is resizable. It is getting scrollbars when is resized to be too small. The problem is that when I open Child Window and resize the Main Window, then Main Window is never getting scrollbars. In case when the main Window is too small, then I have no any way to observe the content of the Child Window. I have all content of the main Windows is wrapped in Scroll Viewer. Child Window seems to be loaded on top of everything. Is any fix for this? Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: A ChildWindow is modal and therefore you will not be able to use any scrollbars on the parent window until it is closed.

Comment: Thank you. It loks like I will not be able to have scrollbars.